# Error in installing an old version of TailwindCSS | Error: Loading PostCSS "tailwindcss" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss

I am working on a project in which due to the node version I can't use the latest version of TailwindCSS, so I need to install an old version of it (v2.2.19). So, I installed the following versions of the packages:

```
tailwindcss: "^2.2.19"
postcss: "^8"
autoprefixer: "^9"
```

and I have my `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

and I am getting the error: "Error: Loading PostCSS "tailwindcss" plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'"

Does anyone know what I can do to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I was working on a legacy project where I had node version 10. As `tailwindcss` requires node version `12^` and we can't use that in the project.

The only solution I found is to use the standalone `tailwindcss` CLI. You can utilize all the latest features in `tailwindcss` but you need to have the CLI file in your project.

[Here you can find the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli) about using standalone CLI in your project. And [here is the link to download the standalone CLI](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases/tag/v3.3.3) latest release.

I have tried it in a ruby on rails project and it works fine for me.